# Import HTML snippets in HAML?

Tags: html, haml

Is there a way to import HTML snippets or HAML snippets into a HAML file similar to a PHP `include`?

Basically have snippets of HTML for different modules (navigation, footer, carousels, et) in separate files (nav.haml, footer.haml, etc) that can be imported into haml files, so when the haml files are translated into HTML, the imported files HTML is translated as well.

Example:

```
body  
    import(path/to/nav.haml)  
    .container  
        HAML CODE   
    import(path/to/footer.haml)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sir.  It's called a partial.

```
body
  =render 'nav'
  .container
    -# HAML CODE
  =render 'footer'
```

By convention, partials would follow this naming with the underscore prefix:

```
_nav.html.haml
_footer.html.haml
index.html.haml
```

Comment: Awesome! Would 'nav' represent 'nav.haml' located in the same directory?

Comment: Added conventional filenames.  You can reference partials in other directories as well.  If it can't find the partial, the error message does a great job of showing you where it looks.  Very easy to figure that stuff out.

Comment: So I have tried the above method and I get the following error message : Exception on line 4: undefined method `render' for #<Object:0x10dcde958> thoughts?

Comment: `render` is a Rails thing.  Are you using Rails or are you using HAML in another context?

Comment: I am just using HAML to build, via the command line 'haml index.haml index.html, out static HTML pages.  Is this not possible?

Comment: Looks like there's a (ugly) way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386272/

Answer (score 0):

```
body
  = haml(:template_name)
```

if you are using HAML with Sinatra instead of Rails.