# Import HTML without using PHP?

Tags: html

Is there a way to import a block of HTML into a file without the use of something like PHP or Javascript? For my personal website, any time I make a small change to the content of my navbar, I have to go to all of my other pages and make that same change.

Comment: You could probably use an iFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do an internet search for "Server Side Includes for HTML"

Here's a good start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Example:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

Comment: Not sure why this just got a down vote.  SSI is exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Charlie - SSI works just fine on any HTML page. And most all web servers that I know of support it.  It does not require PHP.

Comment: My mistake :) I always thought this was PHP specific, but I'm wrong. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

No feature like the one you described is in the HTML spec, but if you don't have access to server configurations and the like, you can write your code [in a language like HAML and compile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930620/import-html-snippets-in-haml), which would accomplish what you described without any server-side work.